# What does second parameter in ClickHouse function toDateTime64 mean?

Tags: database, clickhouse

ClickHouse has function toDateTime64() to convert string into DateTime64 data type.

Example from official documentation:

```
SELECT * FROM dt WHERE timestamp = toDateTime64('2019-01-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Europe/Moscow')
```

It takes 3 parameters:

1. Date string
2. Integer
3. Timezone

But there is no info about the second parameter. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's precision.

3 is milliseconds (`2019-01-01 03:00:00.000`),
6 is microseconds (`2019-01-01 03:00:00.000000`)
and so on.

You can find more info in DateTime64 datatype description https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/datetime64/